# Can't disable focused inbox in Outlook 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

I have a user who somehow ended up with Focused Inbox enabled and doesn't want it. However, I found I am unable to disable it. According to various guides, there should be a button in the View tab of the ribbon, but it wasn't there by default. When I added the whole "focused inbox" group, it blocked off a chunk of the ribbon for the tab, but the button wasn't there, and was greyed out in ribbon settings. When I added a custom group and directly added the command to it, the button showed up, but greyed out, although it was no longer greyed out in settings:

[image: Screenshot from Outlook's menu]

Answer (score 1):

You can turn off Focused Inbox in Outlook desktop in the menu to the right of the Focused/Other tabs via unticking the 'Show Focused Inbox' if it's available.
['Show Focused Inbox' in Outlook Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XgbRH.jpg)

If the option is not available, also try disabling the feature from OWA Options. You will need to restart the Outlook client to make the changes to take effect.
[Turn off Focused Inbox in OWA Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2GmJ.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately, that didn't work. The option isn't there in desktop, and changing it in OWA had no effect. FWIW, both my OWA and the user's OWA had Focused Inbox enabled, but my desktop client doesn't have it enabled, while the user's does. Seems to be independent of each other.

Comment: Whether you have Modern Authentication enabled for the tenant? Modern Authentication is required for the Focused Inbox button to show under the View tab. See this article which discussed a similar issue: [Focused Inbox is not available in Outlook.](https://www.slipstick.com/office-365/focused-inbox-outlook/)

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful. Their focussed mailbox is rather silly IMHO and quite hard to turn off.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out how to do it. Start your mail application (Windows 10 application), get in the setting, under "Inbox Priority". Deactivate the option and restart Outlook 2016.

You should now see the icon "Show focused Inbox" to deactivate this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and situation with the greyed out button.  I got it to work by first turning off Focused Inbox through Outlook on the Web and then restated my desktop Outlook app, the icon for Focused Desktop was now in color (no longer greyed out) and I turned it off in the desktop app as well.